# Is it possible to target a Windows Phone app so it only appears to 7 clients?

Tags: windows-phone

I am working on an app and have created two projects.  One project targets Windows Phone 7.x and doesn't use any of the new features offered in 8. The other app targets and uses features available only in Windows Phone 8, includes expanded tile imagery and different controls (LongListSelector).

When I attempted to publish my 7 app, I see that it would be available to clients who run Windows Phone 8, I do not want this.  I am also worried if I upload my app for 8 it will prevent me from uploading my app for 7, since they would both have the same name, ideally.

Am I missing something, or is it not possible to explicitly support only 7? If this is not possible, what options do I have?

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 3):

If you publish only the WP7 package, then it will be available for both WP7 and WP8 devices. If you then publish a second WP8 package, then this one will be available for WP8 devices and the WP7 package will be available only to the WP7 devices. Unfortunately you cannot publish WP7 package in a way it won't be available for WP8 devices.

As far as I heard from local Microsoft guy hiding WP7 app on WP8 devices is only available for Microsoft, OEM and VIP app producers (lot of WP7 games, Microsoft and Nokia apps is not available on WP8 devices), but not for regular developers.

You should either publish both your packages at the same time, or you might try to contact local Microsoft representative, if there is something they can do.

Comment: According to this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpsubmit/thread/789b3017-d242-4151-9d0b-84c85c4b3c24

Microsoft will not provide any way to disable WP8 support on WP7 apps.

> "Unfortunately, we won't have a method in place for developers to opt of 8.0 distribution. We encourage you to test your apps for 8.0 compatability."

Comment: I wonder what happens if you publish both a WP7 and WP8 version, and then unpublish the WP8 one...